# MS Access VBA Remove Specific Characters from String

Tags: ms-access, vba

I have a report, selecting from a table called "Volunteers". The entire WHERE clause is constructed in VBA at runtime, based on the following parameters selected on the form

Volunteer Type: One of 2 checkboxes

Region: 1 dropdown - but, in VBA, each region could be any number of offices

Position: 4 option multi-select

County: 70 option multi-select

My report has to compile all of these dynamic variables at runtime.

What I thought would be my last question - regarding Counties - actually doesn't work, and that's where I'm at now.

In the "Volunteer" table, each of the 70 Counties is its own Boolean field.

The ReportFrom represents Counties as Strings. In order to loop through up to 70 selections, in an OR statement, to evaluate String against True/False, the following solution was supplied:

```
Dim s As Variant
Dim ctl As Control
Dim t As TCondition
Set ctl = Me.Counties
If ctl.ItemsSelected.Count <> 0 Then
    For Each s In ctl.ItemsSelected
        t.WhereCondition = t.whereCondition & ctl.ItemData(s) & " = -1 OR"
    Next s
    ' trim trailing " OR"
    t.WhereCondition = Left(t.WhereCondition, Len(t.WhereCondition)-3)
End If
```

This worked out GREAT except when compiling these selections with the other parameters of the WHERE clause. There were not enough parens around this selection, and it was not filtering records properly.

I attempted several solutions - the closest of which was this:

```
If ctl.ItemsSelected.Count <> 0 Then
    For Each s In ctl.ItemsSelected
        t.WhereCondition = t.WhereCondition & "((" & ctl.ItemData(s) & ") = -1) OR )"
    Next s
    t.WhereCondition = Left(t.WhereCondition, Len(t.WhereCondition) - 4)
End If
```

The problem is Trimming 4 characters removes the RParen that I *need* in order for this statement to properly filter the report. Trimming only 3 leaves a trailing "O".

I need to somehow remove just the trailing OR, keeping the trailing parenthesis.

Is there a way to do that?

(I hate posting afternoon (EST) questions, as I won't be able to follow up until tomorrow, but, I've been racking my brain on this all day)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The not-so-glorious but quick-and-dirty way to do this would be:

```
t.WhereCondition = Left(t.WhereCondition, Len(t.WhereCondition) - 4)
t.WhereCondition = t.WhereCondition & ")"
```

Or just:

```
t.WhereCondition = Left(t.WhereCondition, Len(t.WhereCondition) - 4) & ")"
```

Comment: This was helpful, and just what I was looking for. Thanks! Apologies for the delay. This db is giving me grey hairs.

Answer (score 0):

A coworker managed to approach this a different way, and encapsulated the dynamic WHERE clause in a different section of code

```
t.WhereCondition = "(" & t.WhereCondition & ") AND
```

Encasing the current WHERE as it's built looks like it supplies the extra separation needed to properly filter records.